# Apache Spark PySpark Connect to MSSQL Database JDBC

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to connect to a SQL Server database on my localhost / laptop using Apache Spark.  But after numerous attempts, and closely following documentation online, I can not successfully connect to the database and read/write queries.

I am using Python 3.7.3 on Windows 10 64 bit Operating System, and I have the Anaconda Distribution of Python.

I have downloaded the Jar JDBC File and placed it into the Spark folder (within my Anaconda folder for pyspark).  I downloaded the Microsoft JDBC Driver 7.4 here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=57782.

## Updated 12/31 18:46 EST***

## Step 1 spark classpath using Anaconda Prompt -> pyspark -> hit enter, then enter the following command below

```
bin/spark-shell--driver-class-path "C:/Users/ypv0rfh/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda3/pkgs/pyspark-2.4.3-py_0/site-packages/pyspark/jars/mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre12.jar" --jars "C:/Users/ypv0rfh/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda3/pkgs/pyspark-2.4.3-py_0/site-packages/pyspark/jars/mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre12.jar"
```

## Step 2 launch jupyter lab from anaconda prompt, and run following code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession\
    .builder\
    .master('local[*]')\
    .appName('Connection-Test')\
    .getOrCreate()

jdbcDF = spark.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=RDM_AUTO_PROCESS") \
    .option("driver","com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver") \
    .option("dbtable", "dbo.RDM_145_TOTAL") \
    .option("user", "windows_userid") \
    .option("password", "windows_password") \
    .load()
```

## Error message received:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o38.load.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

Comment: Have you tried without local authentication?  In other words, using a username and password.  Might want to start there to separate connection errors vs authentication errors.

Comment: I did try with entering my user name and password, and did not successfully connect.  Also configured the Sql Server password requirements.  I will try again,  I can post these steps.  I will try that out.  Thank you for your reply.

Comment: No problem! I use Spark to MYSQL connectors with JDBC so this is a little out of my area.  What I do, is put the JDBC connector in the /usr/lib/spark/jars folder.  Then, you don't need to specify the driver when you attempt to connect.

Comment: I have the jar in the python folder (listed above in the description).  I didnt specify the driver i think.  I also changed it to user / password instead of local authentication.  Still getting an error.  Any thoughts?

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver     That error is what I am referring to.  You did specify the driver by saying:  .option("driver", 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver').  Take that option out and see if the error changes.

Comment: I removed .option("driver", 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver') and the new error message is listed above in the description as of 11:52 NY ET.  I am reading a book https://runawayhorse001.github.io/LearningApacheSpark/pyspark.pdf and they are saying to do something like this: properties ={'driver': 'org.postgresql.Driver', 'password': pw,'user˓': user}.  should i try this?

Comment: No. You aren't using postgresql.driver.  You have spark downloaded locally right? not just the pyspark package.  If so, then you can put the Jar file in the  /usr/lib/spark/jars

Comment: yes im using a sql server driver.  i just posted what im doing with trying to follow the textbook https://runawayhorse001.github.io/LearningApacheSpark/pyspark.pdf Im using com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver and have it saved in pyspark folder in file path listed in description.  I have not downloaded spark, just the pyspark.  Should i download Spark from the spark website?  I will try that now.  downloading Apache Spark from the main website of spark http://spark.apache.org/downloads.html

Comment: I downloaded Spark regular, but having issues with Python interopability now.  The other guy Jayadeep said i can just use pyspark. thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation as mentioned [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html) you can try something like below, you might have to put the location in quotes as I believe you are running in a windows environment.

```
bin/spark-shell --driver-class-path /C:/Users/ypv0rfh/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda3/pkgs/pyspark-2.4.3-py_0/site-packages/pyspark/jars/sqljdbc42.jar --jars /C:/Users/ypv0rfh/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda3/pkgs/pyspark-2.4.3-py_0/site-packages/pyspark/jars/sqljdbc42.jar
```

Then in your spark application you would need to use the jdbc options as below

```
jdbcDF = spark.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql:dbserver") \
    .option("driver","com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver") \
    .option("dbtable", "schema.tablename") \
    .option("user", "username") \
    .option("password", "password") \
    .load()
```

Comment: do you reccomend that i install Spark, instead of just using Pyspark that i installed using Anaconda?

Comment: Not needed, when you run pyspark command just add the driver class path and the jars along with it and start the shell.

Comment: So i opened the cmd file located here - C:/Users/ypv0rfh/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda3/pkgs/pyspark-2.4.3-py_0/site-packages/pyspark/bin/spark-shell.cmd.  After that, I pasted in this string bin/spark-shell --driver-class-path /C:/Users/ypv0rfh/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda3/pkgs/pyspark-2.4.4-py_0/site-packages/pyspark/jars/mssql-jdbc-7.2.2.jre8.jar --jars /C:/Users/ypv0rfh/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda3/pkgs/pyspark-2.4.4-py_0/site-packages/pyspark/jars/mssql-jdbc-7.2.2.jre8.jar   then i get syntax error.

Comment: I ran the command you reccomended but its still not working.  any thoughts?  appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully executed a JDBC command to my local host Database.

I respectfully claim that this is not explicitly explained in the documentation, and I wish to add more comprehensive documentation to Pyspark literature in the core documentation.  As this is a very useful feature.

Here are the steps I followed:

## 1. issued the following command in a blank fresh Anaconda prompt.

```
pyspark --driver-class-path /C:/Users/ypv0rfh/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda3/pkgs/pyspark-2.4.3-py_0/site-packages/pyspark/jars/sqljdbc42.jar --jars /C:/Users/ypv0rfh/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda3/pkgs/pyspark-2.4.3-py_0/site-packages/pyspark/jars/sqljdbc42.jar
```

## 2. Added the following configuration to my code:

```
.config("spark.driver.extraClassPath","C:/Users/ypv0rfh/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda3/pkgs/pyspark-2.4.3-py_0/site-packages/pyspark/jars/sqljdbc42.jar")\
```

## 3. Changed SQL Server authentication from windows to sql server authentication and windows, then added a custom user / password for access to database.

## 4. Updated code

```
#LOCAL HOST SPARK 

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession\
    .builder\
    .master('local[*]')\
    .appName('Connection-Test')\
    .config("spark.driver.extraClassPath","C:/Users/ypv0rfh/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda3/pkgs/pyspark-2.4.3-py_0/site-packages/pyspark/jars/sqljdbc42.jar")\
    .getOrCreate()

localDF = spark.write \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=RDM_AUTO_PROCESS") \
    .option("driver","com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver") \
    .option("dbtable", "dbo.RDM_145_TOTAL_TEST") \
    .option("numPartitions", "10")\
    .option("lowerBound", "2019-12-21")\
    .option("upperBound", "2019-12-28")\
    .option("partitionColumn", "weekendingdate")\
    .option("user", "custom_id") \
    .option("password", "custom_pass") \
    .save()
```